# Visual Studio. Отладчик установлен не правильно

Tags: visual-studio

Всем привет. При работе в Visual Studio 2017, при попытке отладки через F5 выскакивает ошибка "Не удается запустить программу <путь>. Отладчик установлен не правильно. Запустите программу Setup для установки или восстановления отладчика". Самое интересное, еще вчера отладчик запускался без проблем, автоматическое обновление отключено, последняя программа которая была установлена так это MS Office 2010, снес VS и заново поставил не помогло, ошибка осталось, подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить данную ошибку.

**И так нашел проблему, у меня почему-то Visual Studio 2017 конфликтует с MS Office, удалил офис и все заработало. Теперь вопрос в другом, как это исправить.**

Comment: На будущее, нельзя просто так взять и снести ПО, такое как VS. Только если вы делали это по ирструкции с майкрософтовского сайта или документации. Иначе могут остаться неудаленные куски.

Comment: Коллега, скажите пожалуйста, а после того как вы удалили офис, вам потребовалось переставлять вижуалку? Или снёс офис и сразу волшебная пилюля?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, нет, не потребовалось, я просто снес и все сразу заработало. Потом установил офис, но уже более старшую версию, до этого стояло 2010, поставил 2016 и все прекрасно работает.

Comment: @Mr.Flatman вчера снёс офис. Не помогло увы.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Попробуйте удалить визуал студию и еще раз поставить, может изменить ситуацию

Comment: @Mr.Flatman не помогло.

Comment: @Mr.Flatman, на конец и у меня получилось. Я после удаления и чистки реестра запустил от администратора. Срослось.